# Problemas usando callback numa ws

Tags: javascript, json, web-service, callback

Estou implementando integração com uma *WS* que busca os dados com base no *cnpj*.

Ao consultar o *WS* e solicitar uma `callback`, ele me retorna o seguinte ERRO:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Acredito que esta tendo uma interpretação errada do *JSon*.

O código que estou usando está neste [repo](https://github.com/GustavoEmmel/valida_cnpj_ws/blob/master/validacnpj.html):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>CNPJ Webservice</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<!-- Adicionando Javascript -->
<script type="text/javascript" >


function meu_callback(conteudo) {

    //Atualiza os campos com os valores.
    document.getElementById('txtRazao').value=(conteudo.nome);
}

function pesquisacep(valor) {

    //Nova variavel "cep" somente com d�gitos.
    var cnpj = valor;

    //Cria um elemento javascript.
    var script = document.createElement('script');

    //Sincroniza com o callback.
    script.src = '//receitaws.com.br/v1/cnpj/'+ cnpj + '/?callback=meu_callback';

    //Insere script no documento e carrega o conte�do.
   document.body.appendChild(script);

};

</script>
</head>

<body>
<!-- Inicio do formulario -->
  <form method="get" action=".">
    <label>Cep:
    <input name="txtCNPJ" type="text" id="txtCNPJ" value="" 
           onblur="pesquisacep(this.value);" /></label><br />
    <label>Nome:
    <input name="txtRazao" type="text" id="txtRazao" size="60" /></label><br />
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

O principal problema é que a asa api url não permitiu CORS. Você não pode ser acessado via ajax. Outro problema que você tem é que você não pode usar acentos ao declarar funções. por exemplo limpa_formulário_cnpj (). Deve ser limpa_formulario_cnpj ().

Prova esto em php:

```
if ($_GET['cnpj']) {
    $url = 'http://receitaws.com.br/v1/cnpj/' . $_GET['cnpj'];
    $dadosSite = file_get_contents($url);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo $dadosSite;
}
```